# why all the javascript grid widgets use div?

Tags: java, ajax, user-interface, grid

As I know, ext grid use div, jquery slickgrid use div.
Is it impossible to use just html table to build a rich ajax grid ?

I think using javascript to build desktop like application is a nightmare?
what's your opinion ? 
I think HTML & HTTP is designed for web sites on internet, not for B/S application running on intranet or lan.
image that there is a another mark up language include many widgets defined in it, such as drop down menu, tree, datagrid etc. and browsers implement this language...

Comment: What is exactly your answer? Is they're an alternative for div ? Div is already quite basic, and table tag isn't used for good reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a `<div>` is a block-level container, with no semantic context.  It's literally just a container, a "dividing block" if you will.

The problem with using `<table>`, is that it should be used for tabular data.  This is both from both the purist perspective (i.e. it's Just Wrong to use it for other things), as well as a pragmatic perspective (browsers will probably assume this is some sort of 2D table and try to render it accordingly).  So if you really want to present some sort of table it's fine, but the frameworks offer functionality that's applicable in a *general* sense, so they can't assume this.

Divs avoid both of these issues, by not giving any particular meaning to their contents.  Thus browsers will not apply any special rendering, making them the perfect "transparent wrapper" to apply appropriate CSS styles/Javascript to.

Webapps aren't perfect, and often a desktop application will be faster and more powerful, but webapps offer a very low barrier to entry.  So long as you already have a browser (and who doesn't), you don't need to install anything.  Additionally, since all the logic is performed on the central server, it's easier to monitor/log/patch/upgrade.  Basically, if you just want to present information and respond to simple commands, it's arguably *better* to roll something out as a webapp, with the client-server model, than desktop apps - simply because it's much easier to maintain, all things being equal.

Comment: A 'grid' is _for_ tabular data.

Comment: Yes, but table tag often has implicit visual features like padding between cells and in IE also disrupts CSS inheritance (at least older) which for some sites makes for a very challenging job getting nice css without a lot of duplication. For a pluggable grid you do not want any extra "features".

Answer (score 0):

I think that divs allow creation of independent and encapsulated components. Otherwise the components will depend on surrounding elements and will not be reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Tables do a lot of tricky things with layout etc, and interaction with the headers, etc etc etc. You can disable all that stuff, but then you're basically down to elements that behave like divs anyway.

I totally agree with your second point - HTML & CSS were not designed with the modern web application in mind. Luckily, Javascript is pretty good and getting better fast. I think HTTP isn't *too* bad (and will be *much* better when WebSockets are common); it's good as a protocol for communication between fallible nodes. Writing desktop-style apps in the browser isn't as easy as it could be - yet.